# inheritance please explain the flow of these program

Tags: java, inheritance

Q. Given:

```
class X {
X() { 
System.out.print(1);
}
X(int x) {
this(); System.out.print(2);
}
}
public class Y extends X {
Y() {
super(6); 
System.out.print(3);
}
Y(int y) {
this(); System.out.println(4);
}
public static void main(String[] a) 
{ 
new Y(5);
}
}
```

Result(Options)

```
A. 13  B. 134  C. 1234  D. 2134  E. 2143
```

Answer : `C`

According to me first we are having default super in java which called constructor
so in my program first it will call default super and prints 1
by using super in my sub class it call argumented constructor AND prints 2
sub class normally prints 3,4.

Is it correct? If it is wrong please rectify it.

Comment: Why dont you try it yourself, and check the results ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it should print 1234.

```
new Y(5)
```

Calls this constractor

```
Y(int y) {

this(); System.out.println(4);

}
```

which by calling "this()" will call Y's default constractor.

> ```
> Y()  { super(6); System.out.print(3); }
> ```

this will call X's "X(int x)"  constructor.
which calls this (on X), so it calls X's default constructor.

Which prints "1".
Then we go back , and printing 2.
Then go back to Y's default constructor and print 3.
Eventually, to Y's (int) constructor, printing 4.

A really difficult way to print "1234" :)